# A tough looking improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How would one solve the following integral:
$$\int_0^{\pi /2} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos (x)}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin (x)}}\right)dx$$
I think I'd need to separate the interval of integration since it's 'double' improper integral. So I chose the point $c=\pi /4$ but didn't really know how to proceed. Tried to sum the fractions and rationalize but didn't work. The solution is zero, so I think one would need some manipulations so that everything cancels out.

Comment: Substitute $u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$.

Comment: What Daniel said. You do need to also justify that the improper integral converges.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to both of you. Got it.
Daniel, feel free to post it as answer if you want

Comment: @windircurse  If you have figured it out, you could also post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working formally, i.e. assuming that everything converges nicely, we get
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
 + \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
 - \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{0} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}u \tag{1} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
 - \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{0} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{2} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x
 - \int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

At (1) we use the suggested substitution $u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$, and at (2) we use the identities
$$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - u\right) = \sin(u)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - u\right) = \cos(u), $$
and replace $u$ with $x$.  Note that we have ignored issues of convergence, which is potentially dangerous.  To finish the problem, we have to show that the original integral converges.  To do this, we can show that the integral converges absolutely, i.e. that
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x < \infty.$$
Applying the triangle inequality, we get
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \right|\,\mathrm{d}x \tag{3} \\
&\le 2\sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x \tag{4}
\end{align}
At (3) we apply the same kind of change of variables and simplification as above in (1) and (2).  At (4) we use the fact that
$$ \sin(x) \ge \frac{x}{2} \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}} \le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x}}.
$$
It remains only to note that the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^p \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty $$
whenever $p > -1$.  Assuming that you believe this, we are done, as this implies that this integral at (4) converges.  If you don't believe it, the argument is a more-or-less straight forward computation:
$$
\lim_{a\to 0} \int_{a}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{a\to 0} \Big[ 2\sqrt{x} \Big]_{x=a}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}
= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} - \lim_{a\to 0} \sqrt{a}
= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}
< \infty.
$$